# Regex to extract Organization names in python

Tags: python, regex

**SAMPLE PROGRAM**

```
import re

demostr = "Department of Microbiology and Immunology. Faculty of Tropical Medicine, Mahidol University, Electronic address: pornsawan.lea@mahidol.ac.th."
org = re.search(r"([A-Z][^\s,.]+[.]?\s[(]?)*(Dept|Association|Office|University|Department)[^,\d]*(?=,|\d)", demostr).group()
print(org)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Department of Microbiology and Immunology. Faculty of Tropical Medicine
```

The program extracts Organization, Department from the given string. It works fine if there is `,` after `Immunology`. but when in cases there is a dot `.` after Organization it extracts wrong output. 
The required output is shown below-

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
Department of Microbiology and Immunology
```

Comment: You need to add `\.` in your alternation  https://regex101.com/r/W5DN2Q/1 check this. you want like this ?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine. @CodeManiac

Comment: You can check answer for more details. what you have missed in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

**You two things in your regex this will work fine**

```
([A-Z][^\s,.]+[.]?\s[(]?)*(Dept|Association|Office|University|Department)[^,\d]*?(?=,|\.|\d)
```

**Thing you have missed**

- `.*` - This is greedy in nature you need to make it lazy because of your requirement.
- `\.` - You didn't included `.` in your alternation.

> Code

```
    import re

    demostr = "Department of Microbiology and Immunology. Faculty of Tropical Medicine, Mahidol University, Electronic address: pornsawan.lea@mahidol.ac.th."
    org = re.search(r"([A-Z][^\s,.]+[.]?\s[(]?)*(Dept|Association|Office|University|Department)[^,\d]*?(?=,|\.|\d)", demostr).group(0)
    print(org)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5DN2Q/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
import re

demostr = "Department of Microbiology and Immunology. Faculty of Tropical Medicine, Mahidol University, Electronic address: pornsawan.lea@mahidol.ac.th."
org = re.search(r"([A-Z][^\s,.]+[.]?\s[(]?)*(Dept|Association|Office|University|Department)[^,\d]*?(?=,|\.|\d)", demostr).group(0)
print(org)
```

Output

```
Department of Microbiology and Immunology
```